# How can I use an Entity Framework class type that is created at runtime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

I have used "code first from db" to create an entity class and include it as the type for a `DbSet` in a `DbContext`.

But I now have a new problem. I need to build an entity class at runtime that represents a row from an Oracle table/view and then use this class in the same manner as the compile time class (I can use Oracle `GetSchema` to provide the information to dynamically create the class type). I want to use it as the type behind a `DbSet` and include this `DbSet` in a `DbContext`.

Can this be done?

Can this `DbSet` be added to an existing/initialized `DbContext`? Or do I have to create a new `DbContext`, somehow add this `DbSet` to the `DbContext` and then initialize the `DbContext`?

I considered using non-generic `DbSet` but I read that this is being dropped from EF 7.

Comment: This might be a good read for you [CodeProject: Unknown Class Dynamically Generated at runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/839640/Unknown-Class-Dynamically-Generated-at-runtime-for)